# Operator defined on a sequence space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence from $\mathbb{C}$, and define an operator $T$ on $l_2 = l_2(\mathbb{N})$ by

$Tu = (a_nu_n), \ u = (u_n) \in dom(T)$

$dom(T) = \{u = (u_n) \in l_2 | (a_nu_n) ∈ l_2\}$.

(i) Show that $T$ is a closed operator.

(ii) Give conditions under which $T$ is bounded.

(iii) Show that

$\sigma_p(T) = \{a_n | n ∈ N\}, \  \sigma (T) = \overline{\sigma_p(T)}$.

(iv) Determine $R(z; T)$ for $z \in \rho(T)$.

ad (i)

I tried to prove with triangle inequlity, but I missed something.

Let $u_n \to u$ and $Tu_n \to v$ and I have to show that $Tu=v$.

So I have $||Tu-v||=||Tu-v+Tu_n-Tu_n|| \le ||Tu_n-v||+||Tu-Tu_n||$ but I don't know how to show that $||Tu-Tu_n||$ goes to $0$.

ad (ii)

I have proved that $T$ is boundef iff $a_n$ is bounded.

ad (iii)

$(T-\lambda I)v=0 \iff \lambda = a_n$

I don't know how to close $\sigma_p(T)$ and how to find $\sigma(T)$, because it seems to me that it will be a set of $\lambda$ where $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n-\lambda} = \infty$

ad (iv)

From (iii) $R(z;T)=(\frac{1}{a_n-\lambda})$

I will be really grateful if somebody tell me how to end those proofs.

Comment: For (i), first you have to show that $u$ is in the domain of $T$

Comment: So I think that I can assume $u_n$ is "decreasing", so $||Tu|| \le ||Tu_n|| < \infty$

Comment: I am sorry, for I did not quite understand your comment. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: Well, to show that $u$ is in domain of $T$, we have to show that $||Tu||$ is finite. We know that $u_n$ is convergent to $u$ and W.L.O.G. I can assume (?) that $u_n$ is decreasing, so $||Tu|| \le ||Tu_n|| < \infty$ but I may be wrong.

Comment: I am a little confused, what do you mean by $u_n$ being decreasing?

Comment: I mean that every coordinate of $u_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: It is almost correct. Recall that in order to have $u_n \in l_2$, we must have $lim_{j \to \infty} u_n^j = 0$ for all $n$. Is this what you are trying to say?

Comment: Not exactly, because I didn't mean that limit is $0$, but I just realized that it has to be $0$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108166/discussion-between-krzysztofb-and-danilo-gregorin).

Comment: I saw your last message in the chat, but I did not quite understand your point. The Closed Graph Theorem, as in Folland's Real Analysis, reads: IF $X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces and $T: X \to Y$ is a closed linear map, then $T$ is bounded. There may be unbounded closed operators, but in this case either $X$ or $Y$ is not Banach, right?

Comment: No. There are closed unbounded operator. For example the adjoint of operator or example from wikipedia. https://prnt.sc/slyuud

Comment: But probably it's graph is not closed. Here, by closed, I am meaning closed graph